# Program Compiles and Runs Fine in Windows IDE, But Won't In Linux - C Language

Tags: c

I have a program written to evaluate postfix expressions. I have the code fully functioning with no compiler warnings when I compile and run it from a Windows IDE (Codeblocks), however, when I try to compile the source code in a Linux environment, I get a ton or warnings. They are listed below:

```
postfix.c: In function ‘infixToPostfix’:
postfix.c:20: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackInit’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:25: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c:36: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackPush’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:31: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c:40: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackIsEmpty’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:37: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c:42: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackPeek’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:43: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c:44: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackPeek’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:43: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c:45: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackPop’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:34: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c:49: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackPush’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:31: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c:54: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackPeek’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:43: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c:56: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackPop’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:34: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c:59: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackPop’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:34: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c:63: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackIsEmpty’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:37: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c:65: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackPop’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:34: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c:69: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackDestroy’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:28: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c: In function ‘evaluatePostfix’:
postfix.c:139: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackInit’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:25: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c:146: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackPush’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:31: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c:150: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackPop’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:34: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c:151: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackPop’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:34: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c:154: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackPush’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:31: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c:159: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackPop’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:34: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
postfix.c:160: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘stackDestroy’ from incompatible pointer type
stack.h:28: note: expected ‘struct stack *’ but argument is of type ‘struct stack **’
/tmp/ccPMgl0G.o: In function `applyOperator':
postfix.c:(.text+0x6bd): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

They all seem to be related to my postfix.c source and my stack.h header. The postfix.c source I completely modified myself, but the stack.h header was supplied by my instructor. All the errors for the postfix.c source seem to point to lines where I have code in the following manner:

> stackInit(&s);

I believe it is referring to my use of the ampersand as a parameter for the function... but there isn't any other way for me to indicate that I am modifying the immediate value of 's' is there? Is there something I should be including before hand? Also... for the 'pow' issue, I have included the header file:

> math.h

So it should be able to reference it... I don't know why it won't compile :/ I have been using this to compile my 3 source files together:

> gcc prog2.c stack.c postfix.c

Is there another way I should be doing this? Thank you in advance.

Source Code:

```
/* function to convert an infix to postfix */
char *infixToPostfix(char *infixStr)
{
    static char pfline[30];
    int i;
    stack * s;
    stackInit(&s);

    char * token = strtok(infixStr, " ");

    for(i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
        pfline[i] = '\0';
    }

    while(token != NULL)
    {
        if(isOperand(token) != 0) {
            strcat(pfline, token);
            strcat(pfline, " ");
        }

        if(isLeftParen(token))
            stackPush(&s, token);

        if(isOperator(token))
        {
            if(!stackIsEmpty(&s))
            {
                if(isOperator(stackPeek(&s)))
                {
                    if(stackPrecedence(stackPeek(&s)) >= inputPrecedence(token))
                        strcat(pfline, stackPop(&s));
                        strcat(pfline, " ");
                }
            }
            stackPush(&s, token);
        }

        if(isRightParen(token))
        {
            while(!isLeftParen(stackPeek(&s)))
            {
                strcat(pfline, stackPop(&s));
                strcat(pfline, " ");
            }
            stackPop(&s);
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    while(!stackIsEmpty(&s))
    {
        strcat(pfline, stackPop(&s));
        strcat(pfline, " ");
    }
    printf("%s\n", pfline);
    stackDestroy(&s);
    return pfline;
}

int evaluatePostfix(char *postfixStr)
{
    stack * s;
    int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;

    stackInit(&s);
    char * token = strtok(postfixStr, " ");

    while(token != NULL)
    {

        if(isOperand(token) != 0)
            stackPush(&s, token);

        if(isOperator(token))
        {
            y = atoi(stackPop(&s));
            x = atoi(stackPop(&s));
            char *str = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
            sprintf(str, "%d", applyOperator(x, y, token));
            stackPush(&s, str);
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    z = atoi(stackPop(&s));
    stackDestroy(&s);
    return z;
}
```

Here is my stack.h header file that was provided which is an interface for the stack:

```
/*
 * This is an interface for a stack of strings.
 *
 */

#ifndef _STACK_H
#define _STACK_H

#include <stdbool.h>

typedef char * stkElement;

struct stkNode {
  stkElement element;
  struct stkNode *next;
};

typedef struct stkNode stkNode;

typedef struct {
  stkNode *top;
} stack;

/* function to initialize a new stack variable */
void stackInit(stack *stkPtr);

/* function to free the memory associated with the stack */
void stackDestroy(stack *stkPtr);

/* function to add an element to the top of the stack */
void stackPush(stack *stkPtr, stkElement element);

/* function that removes the element from the top of the stack */
stkElement stackPop(stack *stkPtr);

/* function that returns a true value if the stack is empty */
bool stackIsEmpty(stack *stkPtr);

/* function that returns the number of elements in the stack */
int stackLength(stack *stkPtr);

/* function that returns the top element in the stack without removing it */
stkElement stackPeek(stack *stkPtr);

#endif  /* _STACK_H */
```

Comment: For math you need to link the math library (in case it in not linking as in your case), try `gcc prog2.c stack.c postfix.c -lm`. As far as the warning go you are passing incorrect type of param. Maybe you need to declare `s` as `struct stack s;` & then call `stackInit(&s);`

Comment: you should add `-Wall` for compilation. show the function declaration of `stackInit(&s);`, pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely not the call to `stackInit()` that is actually wrong - rather it is the declaration of `s`.  You are correct that you need to use `stackInit(&s);` if you want `stackInit()` to modify the variable `s` in the calling function, but if `stackInit()` takes a parameter of type `stack *` then that indicates that you should be declaring `s` as:

```
stack s;
```

Comment: This produced significantly less errors, but now it tells me that "storage size of s isn't known". What exactly does this mean?

Comment: @Newwisdom01: It means that you can't declare a variable of that type because the full definition of the `struct stack` isn't in scope.  At this point I think we would need to see the code your instructor has provided to give good guidance.

Comment: Okay, I've included the header file that is the interface for the stack. Would it have anything to do with the way stkNodes are defined? Do I have to include some sort of identifier involving them when declaring the stack?

Comment: @Newwisdom01: That makes it clearer.  The type is `stack`, not `struct stack`, so `s` should just be declared as `stack s;`.

Comment: caf, you have been an absolute life saver. Thank you so very much! Could you maybe explain why I am required to use a pointer to the stack in a Windows IDE, but declare just the stack in a Linux environment? Or perhaps my terminology is incorrect, but I just don't understand why I had to make such a change in environments.

Comment: @Newwisdom01 You're not required to declare s as a pointer in Windows. Your original code was as broken in Windows as it is in Linux. Your Windows IDE just didn't give you a warning about it.

Comment: @sepp2k And it let me run it with correct output in every example I provided it which is why I'm confused. I'll just continue my studies with it I suppose.

Comment: @Newwisdom01 Ah, right, that's because your struct happens to be exactly as big as a pointer. If you make your struct bigger (for example by adding a second variable to it to store the number of elements in the stack), you'll see that it will suddenly produce entirely broken behavior (and I have to say the fact that your Windows IDE didn't warn you about this would be a good reason to look for another IDE (or enable warnings in the one you're using)).

Comment: @sepp2k Ah, okay I think I understand. So in the future, it would probably be better practice to not even declare the struct as a pointer to avoid unpredictable behavior. Now that I think about it... it doesn't make sense to make it a pointer to the stack. I don't want it to point 'to' the stack, I want it to point to the element IN the stack (which would technically be the nodes right?)that are accessed by the functions related to it. I'll see if I can't figure out how to turn the warnings on in my IDE... so I can hopefully avoid problems like this in the future. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the relevant code, but in order for the error message to make sense, I have to assume that s is a pointer to a stack and stackInit takes a pointer to a stack.

In that case, you should call it as `stackInit(s)` and calling it as `stackInit(&s)` is simply wrong. If you really want stackInit to accept a pointer to a pointer to a stack, you should change the declaration to say so (however I can't imagine that that would make sense).

That being said the only actual compile errror here is "undefined reference to 'pow'", which is unrelated to the warnings. That error can be fixed by linking against the math library using the `-lm` flag to gcc.

Comment: Getting rid of all the ampersands got rid of all the errors, but now my calculations are wrong... it doesn't seem to be getting the proper values when they are popped from the stack :/ I've included the source code at the top of this thread now... assume the ampersands are gone as I removed them in my Linux copy of the source.

Comment: @Newwisdom01 Your code gave incorrect result because you never initialized the pointers you declared. They just pointed at random memory willy nilly. You probably shouldn't have declared them as pointers at all.